# Show that groups of order $2^2\cdot 5^3\cdot7^9$ are not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that groups of order $2^2\cdot 5^3\cdot7^9$ are not simple.

I know that in order to be simple, a group who's normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself. I also know that $2^2\cdot 5^3\cdot7^9 = 20176803500$.

I am unsure how to finish this proof

Comment: Use Sylow theorems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems